# Suppress stacktrace with trigger_error when logging at E_USER_NOTICE

Tags: php, apache, logging

I want to log some messages from my php application in the apache error logs. But I would like this to happen only in the non-production environments.

I found that php has `error_log` to log messages to the error log file but how do I control it to only log if my application is running in the non-prod environments.

Also, I found that there is `trigger_error` which takes a `error type` parameter. And the `error_reporting` setting in php.ini can then decide which error types are actually logged. So, while in dev, I have error_reporting set to `E_ALL` , it is more restricted in production. So, now I can use trigger_log and always log at `E_USER_NOTICE`. This would mean that my message is only shown in the dev log files but not in the production log files.

However, trigger_error also produces a stack trace with every log which is a bit unnecessary for me. How can I disable this stack trace.

Also, am I doing things the right way. How do people generally handle this problem.

Edit:
**I am not trying to suppress error messages. I am trying to provide more *debug* messages in dev**. Things like "Request came with following parameters", "step 1 done", etc. This is really not required in production.

Comment: But what are you gong to do in production environments?

Comment: Why do you want restricted error_reporting in production? Are your programs constantly produce error messages? Ever considered to fix them?

Comment: @YourCommonSense See my edit. I am really just trying to print debug messages to ease development and testing. There are no errors to fix here. Perhaps trigger_error is not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, suppressing error handling is not a good idea - errors have a huge impact on your application performance - and suppressing error reporting does not eliminate the slowdown.

There is no 'trigger_log' in PHP.

The build in error handling in PHP does not generate a stack trace - you must have a custom error handler installed. You need to find it and amend the code if you want to change it's behaviour.

Using 'trigger_error' to record debug events is a very bad idea.

Comment: trigger_log was a typo. My subject used `trigger_error`. I am not trying to suppress error_handling. How do I record debug events in dev only. What is the correct way.

Comment: Use syslog() (in a conditional statement)

Comment: Can syslog() be used to only send to apache error logs. What conditional statement are you referring to, a check for environment, how?

Comment: 1) it's all in the documentation. 2) I don't know how you differentiate between your live and production environemnts 3) see 2

Answer (score 0):

If you want just custom messages sent into error log **manually**, `log_error()` is the function you are looking for.

Comment: You perhaps mean `error_log()`. I already mentioned the problems with using it in my question. Basically, this will log everywhere. How do I selectively log in dev/test only.

Comment: Wrap it in a function that does check a constant?